# PHP static method and static variable, is my solution correct?

Tags: php, class, variables, methods, static

I am working on a test to maintain my skills and I have a question that I am not 100% sure about.

*"Given that we want to run Test::outputTimesFive() the following code snippet has one mistake."*

```
class Test
{
public $_value = 2;

public function __construct()
{
         $this->_value = 3;
     }

 public static function outputTimesFive()
     {
         echo self::$_value * 5;
     }
 }
```

Assuming that I can only point to one line of code with a mistake, of course the line:

```
public $_value = 2;
```

because that was what did not allow static method `Test::outputTimesFive` to properly work.
By adding `static` to that variable, I enabled that method to work just fine, but at the same time I've 'killed' the constructor.

In the question we are talking about executing only that static method, no one talks about creating an instance of that object, so what do you think? Was my thinking correct?

Comment: The static function could [instantiate `self`](http://ideone.com/2nDdTE) then it doesn't break the constructor, but really the intent behind the question isn't clear - it's a bad example - it's also not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.  You might have more luck on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think you're right. I don't like questions expressed like that. The following code snippet has _always_ more than one mistake and You're never sure if smo is trying to trick you with such answer being considered as correct. What's the problem asking about "one critical mistake" or "making such method call work with one correction"?

Comment: Btw. If it was "mark the right answer" test and one of the answers (among proposed lines with error) was simply "no" I would mark that for sure:)

Comment: Thank you very much guys for resposne. I don't want to behave like needy, so I posted my thoughts and answer on that and I wanted to consult with you, without getting minuses, so thanks again :) I will check also on Code Review, thanks - I did not know about this site. They ask like "Which line we should correct to allow Test::outputTimesFive() to run and what number will be in that function output".

Answer (score 0):

The line no. 3 is the correct to point out. The main question is about the static method and we need to do everything to ensure that it will work after correct. Also - I though wrong about constructor, as you guys said - the constructor will anyway work correctly.